# I get MulterError: Unexpected field at wrappedFileFilter error when putting a POST request

Tags: angular, mongodb

I cannot seem to save a product request. The error is:

```
MulterError: Unexpected field
    at wrappedFileFilter (E:\Nuur 2021\Work\Skillshare\eshop-backend\node_modules\multer\index.js:40:19)
    at Multipart.<anonymous> (E:\Nuur 2021\Work\Skillshare\eshop-backend\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:107:7)
    at Multipart.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at HeaderParser.cb (E:\Nuur 2021\Work\Skillshare\eshop-backend\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:358:14)
    at HeaderParser.push (E:\Nuur 2021\Work\Skillshare\eshop-backend\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:162:20)
    at SBMH.ssCb [as _cb] (E:\Nuur 2021\Work\Skillshare\eshop-backend\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:394:37)
    at feed (E:\Nuur 2021\Work\Skillshare\eshop-backend\node_modules\streamsearch\lib\sbmh.js:248:10)
    at SBMH.push (E:\Nuur 2021\Work\Skillshare\eshop-backend\node_modules\streamsearch\lib\sbmh.js:104:16)
    at Multipart._write (E:\Nuur 2021\Work\Skillshare\eshop-backend\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:567:19)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12)
```

And my code is:

```
router.post(`/`, uploadOptions.single('image'), async (req, res) => {

    const file = req.file; 
    if (!file) return res.status(400).send('No image selected')
  
    const category = await Category.findById(req.body.category);
    if (!category) return res.status(400).send('Invalid Category')
    
    const fileName = req.file.filename;
    const basePath = `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/public/uploads`;
    let product = new Product ({

        name: req.body.name,
        image: req.body.image, 
        description: req.body.description,
        richDescription: req.body.richDescription,
        image: `${basePath}${fileName}`, //"http://localhost:3000/public/uploads/image-23234234",
        images: req.body.images,
        brand: req.body.brand,
        price: req.body.price,
        category: req.body.category,
        countInstock: req.body.countInstock, 
        rating: req.body.rating,
        numReviews: req.body.numReviews,
        isFeatured: req.body.isFeatured
        //dateCreated: req.body.dateCreated
    
    })
   product =  await product.save(); 

   if (!product)
   return res.status(500).send('The product cannot be created')
  
   res.send(product); 
})
```

And I inserted Mutler like this,

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        const isValid = FILE_TYPE_MAP [file.mimetype];
        let uploadError = new Error('invalid image type');
        if (isValid) {
            uploadError = null
        }
      cb(uploadError, 'public/uploads')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
//      const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9)
    const fileName = file.originalname.split(' ').join('-');    
    const extension = FILE_TYPE_MAP [file.mimetype];
    cb(null, `${fileName}-${Date.now()}.${extension}`)
    }
  })
```

I tried saving a product using POST request and I get this error. If I remove the product.save command, then the product goes through in Postman without error but obviously doesn't get saved in Mongodb.

Comment: there is a space between `FILE_TYPE_MAP [file.mimetype]`,  it should be `FILE_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype]`

Comment: Thank you, but that is not it. I tried it, same error

Comment: Actually, you were right, space couldve been an issue, and also the other issue was I was using isFeatured as Boolean and I was merely putting random text in it in Postman. So I removed it and it is working now. And removed the spaces you. Thanks.

Comment: usually when working on uploding `file(s)`, the errors come from contentType/mimetype, folder target and source. i saw that you are trying to get info file from` http urll` without read the sream file, i think its better to stream the file to buffer and store it to you local storage

Comment: you can use `Duplex`, its node module native, const `{Duplex} = require('stream')`; this module allows us to store the file without have to download it first.